# Snap.svg виснет при рендере более 500 путей

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация, webgl, snapsvg

Я рендерю кучу Путей (примерно 600), используя `snap.svg` Применяю для анимации `requestAnimationFrame`

Вот код

```
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate)
for(var i = 0 ; i<600; i++) {
path_obj[i].updatePath();
path_obj[i].drawPath();
}
//  updatePath  обновление атрибута d
//  drawPath  установка обновлённого атрибута d
```

Если частиц немного, где то 100, то анимация офигенная, но частиц недостаточно много,  надо где то 10000... Только всё это при десяти тысячах  начинает жёстко виснуть. Кто знает, как решить эту проблему?

*Я слышал, что WebGL успешно с этим справляется, но переписывать и изучать новую технологию не хочется.*

Answer (score 0):

С этим ничего не поделаешь придётся изучать новую технологию. Просто можно изучать не голый WebGL а его высокоуровневые подстройки, например PIXI.js 2D визуализатор графики. Подойдёт)